# Variable outside DispatchQueue.main.async is empty

Tags: swift, grpc

I tried to resolve this error since days but I dont understand why am I getting this error in the first place.

Please help...

```
func createData(request:Crudpb_CreateRequest) -> String {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.response = try! self.client.create(request)

        print("This is response 1: " + self.response.result) // <-------- This is priting the right response
    }
    print("This is response outside DispatchQueue: " + self.response.result) // <------- This is not printing anyvalue
    return self.response.result // <------ This is not
}
```

[image]

Comment: @escaping closures should have a DataType and also should not have an external name (use underscore):    @escaping(_ name: Type) -> Void).   Also, why do you want to have the return value? (String).     The function will return before your closure is processed (if there is some asynchronous stuff)

Comment: Well, what's the code for `client.create(completion:)`? You probably just used the wrong parameter label

Comment: @Alexander Okay I changed the parameter label to the right one what was "request". But now I get another error for the completion function inside the DispatchQueue.main.async .... Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/nlrc12

Comment: @Alexander the code for client.create(completion:) is this : http://prntscr.com/nlrcwy

Comment: @HankMoody The parameter names are completely different, and so are the types. Read the documentation of this API that you're using.

Comment: @Alexander This same function works with just one argument "request" when I dont use any kind of closures. BTW how can I achieve my target using DispatchQueue.main.async with my client.create(request) method?

Comment: @HankMoody I have basically nothing to go off of, and I have *no* idea what you're talking about.

Comment: @Alexander I updated the code to describe what I was talking about. But the problem with this new code now is I can not access variables inside the DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: Your title indicates you're calling `DispatchQueue.main.sync`, which would definitely make this a surprising result. But your actual code calls `.async`, which makes this expected behavior. Which did you mean to use? `async` is asynchronous. The next line of code will run before the async block runs.

Comment: @RobNapier Im sorry, I just corrected the title. I meant to write ".async".

Comment: Then yes, this would be exactly expected. If you're running it asynchronously, why would you expect to have the result immediately? If you want the result immediately, that would be synchronous. That said, this is dangerous because you're accessing `self.response` on two queues, and that's not safe.

Comment: @RobNapier Im calling this code from UI and if I use .sync it crashes

Comment: Why are you dispatching to `.main` from the UI (which runs exclusively from `.main`)?

Comment: @RobNapier This is a singleton. When I push a submit button it is supposed to send data to the server and get a response from it to show in the UI.

Comment: So it's asynchronous? Then you need an asynchronous pattern like @eharo2's answer. The UI queue cannot wait on the network. There's no way to return a value directly that will take a long time to retrieve.

Comment: @RobNapier If I dont use DispatchQueue.main.async then the code works but I dont want my UI to freeze while the api request is being processed.

Comment: Exactly. You need to redesign so that the function returns immediately, and then you process the completion handler when the network finishes. See eharo2's answer for the structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are dispatching whatever work you are doing in your create request method asynchronously, therefor your create data function will not wait for this work to be done to continue its execution, it just calls it and keeps its execution and thats why your value is not modified when you reach your "This is response outside DispatchQueue: " statement.
It will be modified in the capture block that you have created, thats why you need to create an @escaping completion block like they mentioned before, to only return your value when the work you did to obtain it is finished.

```
func createData(request:Crudpb_CreateRequest, with completion: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.response = try! self.client.create(request)
            completion(self.response)
        }
    }
```

Comment: First of all thanks a lot for helping me. Does this function returns a string to the caller or not? I ask this because I see "-> void" in the code you wrote. 

BTW I had to change completion(self.response) to completion(self.response.result) to read it as a string. I tried to call this function from other swift file, it threw missing argument error so I pressed the "fix" button on the error and it added "with: (String) -> void in the calling function. Screenshot: prntscr.com/nlyxg9

Comment: I found the answer for my above question somewhere else but you answered my original question so Im marking your answer as accepted. Thanks a lot for helping me out.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I use @escaping closures:  You don't need a return value in the function, given that the execution of the calling function may end before the closure is finished.  You also need to specify a dataType in the @escaping parameter (Bool in this case)... also, Function types cannot have argument labels, so you must use "_"

```
self.fetchStuff(onCompletion: { (success) in
  if success {
    // Do something
  }
})

func fetchStuff(onCompletion: @escaping (_ success: Bool) -> Void) {
   // Do some asynch stuff
   onCompletion(true)
}
```

Comment: I edited the question. Can you please tell me what went wrong?